# After assignment referance object is not null, how is possible?

Tags: c#, .net, null, pass-by-reference, assignment-operator

The object a is null, but I saw the object b was not null in runtime. Why object b is not null in the case?

```
List<int> a = new List<int>();
List<int> b = a;
a = null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this statement `a` and `b` 'point' to the same object:

```
List<int> b = a;
```

And when you do

```
a = null;
```

`a` 'points' to something different while `b` is untouched (and still points to the list).

Neither a nor b 'are' the list, they only point, or reference the created object

Answer (score 3):

By doing this `List<int> a = new List<int>();` you create one object which is located in the heap and one reference to that object (variable `a`).

By doing this `List<int> b = a;` you create one more reference (variable `b`) to the same object in the heap.

So you got two references and one object.

By doing this `a = null;` you are killing one reference.

So what's left? Reference `b` which refers to the object in the heap.

If you are going to kill `b`, the garbage collector will collect the object from the heap, because it got no references left.

Comment: a.add(5); after varible b's count is 1 in debug.If there are two ref in here why list b's count is 1?

Comment: @slmksy because you have added `one` element into the array. That element in the type of integer and equals to 5.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the `new` keyword as you hiring an apartment for a while. Whenever you use the `new` keyword a new apartment will be reserved for you to use as you like.

In your code, `a` and `b` are just **references** to where our apartment is at in our analogy.

In the line `List<int> a = new List<int>();` you are hiring an apartment and creating a variable `a` that will contain the address of that apartment. Imagine this reference as a note you write in a paper with the address of the apartment.

The line `List<int> b = a;` you are just creating another note with the same address of the apartment that was in the first paper.

You are essentially creating 2 different notes containing the address of the apartment.

When you run `a = null;` it does not change the value of `b` because `a` and `b` are not relate to each other. Using our analogy you are just changing what is written in the first note; the apartment you hired will still be there as long as your second note `b`.

In the analogy, the apartment would be a data block in a special area of the process memory reserved to dynamic allocations called `heap`. The two variables `a` and `b` will be small data allocated in another special area of memory called `stack` containing the address of the data block allocated for the `List<int>`.

Comment: @slmksy sorry I misread the question but just updated my answer. Please take a read again.

Answer (score 0):

like that , b have `new List<int>();` adress , so you set a = null , it dosent matter.

[image]